# How to cancel text reduction when creating a button?

Tags: interface, add-on

I am creating an addon to change the modes of 3D Viewport and I need all modes to be displayed on the button without shortening the text, how can this be implemented? At the moment the plugin is finished and all that remains is to solve the problem with the reduction of text in the buttons
[image]

[image]